# how to set dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows to true value by using javascript in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dom, mozilla

Here I'm trying to close a firefox window using javascript, its only works after `dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows` set to true. But I need to set this by using a `javascript code`. Is it possible or not?  Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: it is not. You don't get to override the browser's `about:config` settings using plain JavaScript - you can write an extension to manipulate them, or you can ask the user to change those values, but normal page JS has no access (nor should it ever) to them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't close any window with `window.close`.

You can use it to close windows that were opened by a script using `window.open`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close